# How to extract a static int from a method after calling it multiple times

Tags: objective-c

For my beginner's level independent study of Objective-C, I was asked to add a counter to a class, so that each time a method was used on it, it would ++. However, I misinterpreted this as "Each time the method the method is called, ++." After realizing how to do what was asked of me, I pondered how I could fashion a method that would return a counter in addition to what the method was called to return. If I were to use a static int in addition to variable++; on each call of the method, how can I extract that value of variable in my main program?

Example code from comment:

```
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f {
    static int fractaddcount;
    fractaddcount++;
    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
    result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post code? That was a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be great to clarify this question :)

Comment: `-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{
 static int fractaddcount;
 fractaddcount++;
 Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
 result.numerator = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
 result.denominator = denominator * f.denominator;
 return result;
}`\

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a tad n00bish at this...

Comment: You could edit the question and put that code there. It would be great to make it self contained - that anyone could copy it, compile it and run it without modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `fractaddcount` an instance variable and initialize it to 0 in the `init` method.  Then it can be accessed by other methods in the class.

Additionally if you make it a `property` other classes will be able to access it.  You can even make the `property` readonly in the .h file and read/write in the  .m file (class extension).

Example:

in .h:

```
@property (non atomic, readonly, assign) int fractaddcount;
```

in .m:

in class extension:

```
@Interface TheClassName ()

@property (non atomic, readwrite, assign) int fractaddcount;

@end
```

in the implementation:

```
@synthesize fractaddcount;
```

in init: This is somewhat optional since when the class is instantiated the ivars are cleared to nil (0).

```
fractaddcount = 0;
```

in your code:

```
self.fractaddcount = self.fractaddcount + 1;
```

Comment: I don't have a separate init method... Am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't need to initialize anything you don't need one.  All objects are guaranteed to be nil on class instantiation.  It is common not to have an init method.

Comment: Then in this case, the way to add a counter to my add: method would be to throw in the @property line to my @interface section, the @ synthesize to my implementation, and throw `self.fractaddcount=self.fractaddcount+1;` to the add: method?

Comment: A couple of things: `fractaddcount` is an int ivar so we assume that class instantiation will set it to 0, that is not a bad assumption.  You don't need to declare the fractaddcount property readonly in the interface, that is just good programming.  If you do then you need to redeclare the  fractaddcount property to read write in a **class extension** not the class implementation.  I am going to add that code to my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a "class extension." I really am a beginner, and only have an interface, implementation, and a main.m. If this is way beyond my skill-set now, I would certainly take that as a valid answer.

Comment: I added a class extension code to the answer, it just goes before the @implimentation in the .m file.  It is three lines `beginning:@Interface TheClassName ()`.

Comment: I have a clarification! I'd like this method to add one to a counter variable for the entire class, not just one instance of a class. I'm not quite sure if this is possible.